# How to assign a type of string or nil in Active Interaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Example

```
array :names do
  string
end
```

how to determine the type of elements as a string and nil.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Active Interaction's [source code](https://github.com/AaronLasseigne/active_interaction/blob/master/lib/active_interaction/filters/array_filter.rb), it seems you can't have multiple types neither nil values inside an array:

```
raise InvalidFilterError, 'multiple filters in array block'
raise InvalidDefaultError, 'default values in array block'
```

You could remove unwanted nil values from the array before calling the interaction though. This would work unless you're expecting exact indices in the array (in which case named indexes e.g. objects should be used instead).

Example:

```
SampleInteraction.run!(names: ['a', 'b', nil, 'd'].compact)
```